# Restore from trash not working. No related log entries

Tags: core, 5.25

We've got a contact deleted to trash today. On restore civi notification states success but the contact remains in trash. The log is silent.

Comment: Hmm, yes I'm seeing the same thing. Might be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it happened in 5.25. I've added a lab ticket: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1784

Will be fixed in 5.26.0.